# Fullsize HDMI vs microHDMI, electrical considerations

Tags: raspberry-pi, electromagnetism, electrical, electricity, hdmi

I'm going to use an HDMI cable in an industrial setting to connect a screen to a Raspberry Pi. We are considering using the Pi 4 instead of the Pi 3 which we have been using earlier. The Pi 4 has switched from the fullsize HDMI connector used in the Pi 3 to a microHDMI connector.

My questions is then if there are any noteworthy electrical differences or concerns when comparing fullsize HDMI and microHDMI? Does microHDMI generate more EMI for example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt there is any meaningful electrical difference; but I would be more concerned about mechanical strength and longevity. I don't thin microHDMI would stand up in an industrial environment.

Comment: I've tried to find any resources or investigations into the durability of microHDMI connnectors, but have so far found nothing at all. Do you have any experience with it, or is it just a hunch/guess that it would be much worse than a full-size HDMI mechanically? The setting it would be used in is a fully-enclosed machine, where no moving parts will come close to it and the machine will rarely be moved. I'd guess that it would be fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only the difference of connector is considered, EMI would be approximately the same. There is very little difference in the pinout in general, and there is no difference in the high speed TMDS lanes which are the most likely to cause EMI. It is just a smaller connector mechanically, no other electrical difference. Most likely there will be more difference in EMI due to changing Pi 3 to Pi 4.